# How to use foreach and get array value using c#

Tags: c#, json

```
{
  "Config": {
    "controls": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "inputs": [
          {
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "xyz",
        "inputs": [
          {
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to get values for `id` , name using `foreach` but I want to exclude `inputs`

I tried like below c# code -

```
var test = JObject.Parse(jsonmessage);
foreach (var x in test["Config"]["controls"])
{
    var key = ((JProperty)(x)).Name;
    var jvalue = ((JProperty)(x)).Value;
}
```

I'm getting exception here :(

> {"Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty'."}

I can't use concrete class because properties may increase sometimes
from json files so have to get values dynamically.

Comment: What kind of exception do you get?

Comment: "I'm getting exception here :(" 1. What exception? 2. On what code line exactly?

Comment: updated question details

Comment: What do you think `(JProperty)(x)` does? What do you think the exception means?

Comment: According to the exception, `x` is a `JObject` and you are trying to cast it to `JProperty`, and this fails

Comment: No i want to take values dynamically bcoz I may have more properties also. so can't use class here

Comment: I understand the exception bcoz type cast goes wrong, then how can i get the values ? any code is useful . thanks :)

Comment: controls is an array of objects, not properties. If you would cast to JObject instead, you could access `control` properties: `(JObject)(x)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simplest way is

```
string json = "{\"Config\": {\"controls\": [{\"id\": 1,\"name\": \"test\",\"inputs\": [{}]},{\"id\": 2,\"name\": \"xyz\",\"inputs\": [{}]}]}}";

var test = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach (var x in test["Config"]["controls"])
{
    var key = x["id"];
    var jvalue = x["name"];
}
```

Now you can read any property from your json string and also use it anywhere by casting it to  required datatype.

Comment: what if I have multiple properties like id,name and so on ... can i do something like `x.propertyname` and for value `x.propertyvalue` ?

Comment: You can not access object by propertyname as it is dynamic so you have to pass the key name. e.g. x["propertyname"]

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally just deseralize the json into a class here.

example:

```
var test = Json.Convert<MyClass>(jsonmessage);
foreach (var x in test.Config.controls)
{
    var key = x.id
}
```

Where `MyClass` would like like the following:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public Config Config { get;set }
}

public class Config 
{
    public IEnumerable<Controls> controls { get;set; }
}

public class Controls
{
    public int id { get;set }
    public string name { get;set; }
}
```

Comment: No I can't use `MyClass` concrete class bcoz there are multiple properties which may vary . so want to achieve this dynamically .

Comment: @Neo You should really mention that in the OP. That's pretty key information. What exactly is dynamic?

Comment: updated my question sorry , could you please help me to get values dynamically

Answer (score 1):

When iterating like this:

```
foreach (var x in test["Config"]["controls"])
{
    // On first iteration:
    // x = 
    // {
    //     "id": 1,
    //     "name": "test",
    //     "inputs": [{}]
    // }

    // therefore you could do:
    var id = x["id"];
    var name = x["name"];

    // or use another foreach
    foreach(var prop in x)
    {
        // and here you might be able to do what you wanted to
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bit of LINQ to extract id and name.

```
var test = JObject.Parse(json);
var list = test["Config"]["controls"].AsQueryable().Select(x => new Tuple<int, string>(int.Parse(x["id"].ToString()), x["name"].ToString()));
```

Now you have got a list of Tuples whose first item is the id and second item is the name.

```
//This is for demo : print id and name here
foreach(var tuple in list)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Id = {0}, Name = {1}", tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
}
```